# SVM in R language

Tags: svm

I have two data set like below
1st dataset

```
x1    x2      types
1     3         1
2     4         1
3     5         1
```

2nd dataset

```
x1    x2      types
4     8         -1
2     10        -1
3     12        -1
```

in `1st dataset x2 = 2+x1`
amd `2nd x2= 2*x1`
how can I train the dataset for SVM in R language 
so that if i input another data like(2,4) it will present in class 2

Comment: Some help info you can find [here](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/R_example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell svm() which is the class that has the label that describes you data, what is your dataset, and what parameters you want to use.

For example, supposing all of your data is together on a dataframe called "dataset" you could call:

svm(types ~., data = dataset,  kernel = "radial", gamma = 0.1, cost = 1)

To check what parameters are better for your problem you can use tune.svm().

tune.svm(types~., data = dataset, gamma = 10^(-6:-1), cost = 10^(-3:1))